# Smooth scrolling in listview with multiple row layouts

Tags: android, performance, android-listview, scroll

I have a listview which inflates 4 different types of row layouts depending on the position(overriden  getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position) to achieve it)  .Each row has an Image and other textviews and buttons . I am loading the image in a seaparate thread . I am using android viewholder pattern to cache the viewholders for each row type .

When I scroll from one kind of row layout to another row layout I observe a jerkiness in scrolling .

Any pointers to improve will be appreciated.

```
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

    int width = (Utils.getWidth(mCtx)-Utils.dpToPx(40, mCtx)) ;

    final FeedViewData mFeedViewData = getFeedViewData().get(arg0);

    if( getItemViewType(arg0) == Utils.SMALL_OBJECT_LEFT){
        ObjectViewHolder viewHolderLeft = new ObjectViewHolder() ;
        float imgWidth = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.6f);
        float descWidth = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.4f) ;
        float rowHeight = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.6f)*Utils.PRODUCT_PRI_ASPECT_RATIO;
        if(arg1==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_multipane_left_image, arg2, false);
            viewHolderLeft.row = arg1.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);

            viewHolderLeft.imagesLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);
            viewHolderLeft.objImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_object);
            viewHolderLeft.price = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_price);

            viewHolderLeft.paneMargin = arg1.findViewById(R.id.pane_margin);
            viewHolderLeft.descriptionsLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_description);

            viewHolderLeft.likeActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_like);
            viewHolderLeft.likeCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_like_count);

            viewHolderLeft.shareActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_share);
            viewHolderLeft.shareCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_count);

            viewHolderLeft.commentActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_comment);
            viewHolderLeft.commentCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_comment);

            viewHolderLeft.activityLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_activity);
            viewHolderLeft.userImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_activity);
            viewHolderLeft.timeline = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_timeline);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            imgLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderLeft.objImg.setLayoutParams(imgLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            rlLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            rlLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderLeft.imagesLayout.setLayoutParams(rlLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams marginLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Utils.dpToPx(1,mCtx),(int)rowHeight)); 
            marginLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.layout_image);
            viewHolderLeft.paneMargin.setLayoutParams(marginLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams descLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)descWidth,(int)rowHeight)); 
            descLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.pane_margin);
            descLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderLeft.descriptionsLayout.setLayoutParams(descLp);          

            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderLeft.objImg, (int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);

            arg1.setTag(viewHolderLeft);

        }
        else{
            viewHolderLeft = (ObjectViewHolder)arg1.getTag();               
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderLeft.objImg, (int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
        }       

        String mLeftImgUrl = null;

        mLeftImgUrl = Utils.m_img_base_url+
                mFeedViewData.getProductId() + "/pri-" + mFeedViewData.getFileidn()+".jpg";

        try{
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mLeftImgUrl, viewHolderLeft.objImg, 
                    new SingleImageListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderLeft.objImg));
        }
        catch(Exception e){             
            return null;
        } 

        viewHolderLeft.objImg.setOnClickListener(new ProdImageOnClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        if(mFeedViewData.getIsLoved())
            viewHolderLeft.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundColor(mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.auth_btn_color_normal));
        else
            viewHolderLeft.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_pink_button);

        viewHolderLeft.likeActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new LikeActionListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderLeft.likeActionLayout));
        viewHolderLeft.shareActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new ShareClickListener(mLeftImgUrl));
        viewHolderLeft.commentActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnCommentClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        viewHolderLeft.price.setTypeface(Utils.getFontForRupeeSymb(mCtx));
        viewHolderLeft.price.setText(Html.fromHtml( "` " + "</font>" + "<b>" + mFeedViewData.getPrice() + "</b>"));
        if(!mFeedViewData.getLikeCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderLeft.likeCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getLikeCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getShareCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderLeft.shareCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getShareCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getRevCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderLeft.commentCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getRevCount() + ")");

        int minutes=0;

        if(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp()!=""){
            long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp());
            minutes = (int)((int) (timeDiff/1000))/60;
        }

        if(mFeedViewData.getUsername().length()>0){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getTnPic(), viewHolderLeft.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderLeft.userImg)); 
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getUsername() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getDoer()), 0, mFeedViewData.getUsername().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderLeft.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                 
            }               
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getReview()!=null){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getReview().getTnUrl(), viewHolderLeft.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderLeft.userImg)); 
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getReview().getReview()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getReview().getId()), 0, mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderLeft.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                 
            }               
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getActivity().length()>0){
            String activityText;
            if(mFeedViewData.getActivity().equals("null"))
                activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "A user: "+ "</b>" + "" +" ").toString();
            else
                activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "A user: "+ "</b>" + "" +" "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setText(activityText);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderLeft.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                 
            }   
            viewHolderLeft.userImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blank_profile);
        }

        if(feedType == Utils.ADAPTER_FEED_TUTORIAL){
            viewHolderLeft.userActivity.setClickable(false);
            viewHolderLeft.objImg.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
    else if(getItemViewType(arg0) == Utils.SMALL_OBJECT_RIGHT){
        ObjectViewHolder viewHolderRight = new ObjectViewHolder();
        float imgWidth = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.6f);
        float descWidth = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.4f) ;
        float rowHeight = (width-Utils.dpToPx(1, mCtx))*(0.6f)*Utils.PRODUCT_PRI_ASPECT_RATIO;

        if(arg1==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_multipane_right_image, arg2, false);          
            viewHolderRight.row = arg1.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);

            viewHolderRight.imagesLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);
            viewHolderRight.objImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_object);
            viewHolderRight.price = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_price);

            viewHolderRight.paneMargin = arg1.findViewById(R.id.pane_margin);

            viewHolderRight.descriptionsLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_description);

            viewHolderRight.likeActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_like);
            viewHolderRight.likeCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_like_count);

            viewHolderRight.shareActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_share);
            viewHolderRight.shareCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_count);

            viewHolderRight.commentActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_comment);
            viewHolderRight.commentCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_comment);

            viewHolderRight.activityLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_activity);
            viewHolderRight.userImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
            viewHolderRight.userActivity = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_activity);
            viewHolderRight.timeline = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_timeline);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams descLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)descWidth,(int)rowHeight)); 
            descLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            descLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderRight.descriptionsLayout.setLayoutParams(descLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams marginLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Utils.dpToPx(1,mCtx),(int)rowHeight)); 
            marginLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.layout_description);
            viewHolderRight.paneMargin.setLayoutParams(marginLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));

            imgLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderRight.objImg.setLayoutParams(imgLp);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            rlLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.pane_margin);
            rlLp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
            viewHolderRight.imagesLayout.setLayoutParams(rlLp);

            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderRight.objImg, (int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);

            arg1.setTag(viewHolderRight);
        }
        else{
            viewHolderRight = (ObjectViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderRight.objImg, (int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
        }

        String mRightImgUrl = null;

        mRightImgUrl = Utils.m_img_base_url+
                mFeedViewData.getProductId() + "/pri-" + mFeedViewData.getFileidn()+".jpg";

        try{

            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mRightImgUrl, viewHolderRight.objImg, 
                    new SingleImageListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderRight.objImg));

        }
        catch(Exception e){             
            return null;
        } 

        viewHolderRight.objImg.setOnClickListener(new ProdImageOnClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        if(mFeedViewData.getIsLoved())
            viewHolderRight.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundColor(mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.auth_btn_color_normal));
        else
            viewHolderRight.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_pink_button);

        viewHolderRight.likeActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new LikeActionListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderRight.likeActionLayout));
        viewHolderRight.shareActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new ShareClickListener(mRightImgUrl));
        viewHolderRight.commentActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnCommentClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        viewHolderRight.price.setTypeface(Utils.getFontForRupeeSymb(mCtx));
        viewHolderRight.price.setText(Html.fromHtml( "` " + "</font>" + "<b>" + mFeedViewData.getPrice() + "</b>"));
        if(!mFeedViewData.getLikeCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderRight.likeCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getLikeCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getShareCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderRight.shareCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getShareCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getRevCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderRight.commentCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getRevCount() + ")");

        int minutes=0;

        if(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp()!=""){
            long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp());
            minutes = (int)((int) (timeDiff/1000))/60;
        }

        if(mFeedViewData.getUsername().length()>0){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getTnPic(), viewHolderRight.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderRight.userImg));   
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getUsername() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getDoer()), 0, mFeedViewData.getUsername().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderRight.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }               
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getReview()!=null){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getReview().getTnUrl(), viewHolderRight.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderRight.userImg));   
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getReview().getReview()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getReview().getId()), 0, mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderRight.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }               
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getActivity().length()>0){
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "A user: "+ "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setText(activityText);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderRight.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }   
            viewHolderRight.userImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blank_profile);
        }

        if(feedType == Utils.ADAPTER_FEED_TUTORIAL){
            viewHolderRight.userActivity.setClickable(false);
            viewHolderRight.objImg.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
    else if(getItemViewType(arg0) == Utils.MAGAZINE_OBJECT){
        MagazineViewHolder viewHolderMag = new MagazineViewHolder();
        float imgWidth = width/2;
        float descWidth = width;
        float rowHeight = ((width)/2)*Utils.MAG_ASPECT_RATIO;
        if(arg1==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_magazine, arg2, false);
            viewHolderMag.row = arg1.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);

            viewHolderMag.imagesLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);
            viewHolderMag.magImgLeft = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_object_1);
            viewHolderMag.magImgRight = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_object_2);
            viewHolderMag.price = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_price);

            viewHolderMag.likeActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_like);
            viewHolderMag.likeCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_like_count);

            viewHolderMag.shareActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_share);
            viewHolderMag.shareCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_count);

            viewHolderMag.commentActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_comment);
            viewHolderMag.commentCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_comment);

            viewHolderMag.activityLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_activity);
            viewHolderMag.userImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
            viewHolderMag.userActivity = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_activity);
            viewHolderMag.timeline = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_timeline);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgLp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            imgLp1.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            viewHolderMag.magImgLeft.setLayoutParams(imgLp1);
            viewHolderMag.magImgRight.setLayoutParams(imgLp1);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)descWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            viewHolderMag.imagesLayout.setLayoutParams(rlLp);

            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderMag.magImgLeft,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderMag.magImgRight,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);

            arg1.setTag(viewHolderMag);
        }
        else{
            viewHolderMag = (MagazineViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderMag.magImgLeft,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderMag.magImgRight,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
        }

        String mImgUrlLeft = Utils.m_img_mag_base_url+mFeedViewData.getFileidn().split("-")[1]+".jpg";
        String mImgUrlRight =  Utils.m_img_mag_base_url+mFeedViewData.getFileidn().split("-")[2];

        try{
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mImgUrlLeft, viewHolderMag.magImgLeft,
                    new MagazineImageListener(viewHolderMag.magImgLeft));
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mImgUrlRight, viewHolderMag.magImgRight,
                    new MagazineImageListener(viewHolderMag.magImgRight));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        } 

        viewHolderMag.imagesLayout.setOnClickListener(new ProdImageOnClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        viewHolderMag.price.setTypeface(Utils.getFontForRupeeSymb(mCtx));
        viewHolderMag.price.setText(Html.fromHtml( "` " + "</font>" + "<b>" + mFeedViewData.getPrice() + "</b>"));

        //TODO: Remove once mag has price
        viewHolderMag.price.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(!mFeedViewData.getLikeCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderMag.likeCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getLikeCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getShareCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderMag.shareCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getShareCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getRevCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderMag.commentCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getRevCount() + ")");

        if(mFeedViewData.getIsLoved())
            viewHolderMag.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundColor(mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.auth_btn_color_normal));
        else
            viewHolderMag.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_pink_button);

        viewHolderMag.shareActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new ShareClickListener(mFeedViewData.getMagImage()));
        viewHolderMag.likeActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new LikeActionListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderMag.likeActionLayout));
        viewHolderMag.commentActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnCommentClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        int minutes=0;

        if(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp()!=""){
            long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp());
            minutes = (int)((int) (timeDiff/1000))/60;
        }

        if(mFeedViewData.getUsername().length()>0){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getTnPic(), viewHolderMag.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderMag.userImg));   
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getUsername() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getDoer()), 0, mFeedViewData.getUsername().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderMag.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                  
            }               
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getReview()!=null){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getReview().getTnUrl(), viewHolderMag.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderMag.userImg));   
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getReview().getReview()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getReview().getId()), 0, mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderMag.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                  
            }               
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getActivity().length()>0){
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "A user: "+ "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setText(activityText);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderMag.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                  
            }   
            viewHolderMag.userImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blank_profile);
        }

        if(feedType == Utils.ADAPTER_FEED_TUTORIAL){
            viewHolderMag.userActivity.setClickable(false);
            viewHolderMag.imagesLayout.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
    else if(getItemViewType(arg0) == Utils.SCRAP_OBJECT){
        ObjectViewHolder viewHolderScrap = new ObjectViewHolder();
        float imgWidth = width;
        float rowHeight = (width)*Utils.SCRAPBOOK_ASPECT_RATIO;
        if(arg1==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            arg1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_single_pane, arg2, false);
            viewHolderScrap.row = arg1.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);

            viewHolderScrap.imagesLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_image);
            viewHolderScrap.objImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_object);
            viewHolderScrap.price = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_price);           

            viewHolderScrap.likeActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_like);
            viewHolderScrap.likeCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_like_count);

            viewHolderScrap.shareActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_share);
            viewHolderScrap.shareCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_count);

            viewHolderScrap.commentActionLayout = (RelativeLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_action_comment);
            viewHolderScrap.commentCount = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_share_comment);

            viewHolderScrap.activityLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1.findViewById(R.id.layout_activity);
            viewHolderScrap.userImg = (ImageView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_activity);
            viewHolderScrap.timeline = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.text_timeline);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imgLp1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            viewHolderScrap.objImg.setLayoutParams(imgLp1);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlLp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int)imgWidth,(int)rowHeight));
            viewHolderScrap.imagesLayout.setLayoutParams(rlLp);

            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderScrap.objImg,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);

            arg1.setTag(viewHolderScrap);
        }
        else{
            viewHolderScrap = (ObjectViewHolder)arg1.getTag();
            ImageSizeUtils.defineTargetSizeForView(viewHolderScrap.objImg,(int) imgWidth,(int)rowHeight);
        }

        String mNormalImgUrl = null;
        mNormalImgUrl = Utils.m_img_scrap_base_url + mFeedViewData.getScrapId() + ".png";

        try{
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mNormalImgUrl, viewHolderScrap.objImg, 
                    new SingleImageListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderScrap.objImg));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        } 

        viewHolderScrap.objImg.setOnClickListener(new ProdImageOnClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        if(mFeedViewData.getIsLoved())
            viewHolderScrap.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundColor(mCtx.getResources().getColor(R.color.auth_btn_color_normal));
        else
            viewHolderScrap.likeActionLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_pink_button);

        viewHolderScrap.likeActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new LikeActionListener(mFeedViewData,viewHolderScrap.likeActionLayout));
        viewHolderScrap.shareActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new ShareClickListener(mNormalImgUrl));
        viewHolderScrap.commentActionLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnCommentClickListener(mFeedViewData));

        viewHolderScrap.price.setTypeface(Utils.getFontForRupeeSymb(mCtx));
        viewHolderScrap.price.setText(Html.fromHtml( "` " + "</font>" + "<b>" + mFeedViewData.getPrice() + "</b>"));

        //TODO:Remove once scrap has price
        viewHolderScrap.price.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(!mFeedViewData.getLikeCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderScrap.likeCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getLikeCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getShareCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderScrap.shareCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getShareCount() + ")");
        if(!mFeedViewData.getRevCount().equals("0"))
            viewHolderScrap.commentCount.setText(" (" + mFeedViewData.getRevCount() + ")");

        int minutes=0;

        if(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp()!=""){
            long timeDiff = System.currentTimeMillis() - Long.parseLong(mFeedViewData.getTimestamp());
            minutes = (int)((int) (timeDiff/1000))/60;
        }

        if(mFeedViewData.getUsername().length()>0 && (!mFeedViewData.getActivity().equals("null")) && mFeedViewData.getActivity().length()>0){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getTnPic(), viewHolderScrap.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderScrap.userImg));   

            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getUsername() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getDoer()), 0, mFeedViewData.getUsername().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderScrap.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }                           
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getReview()!=null){
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(mFeedViewData.getReview().getTnUrl(), viewHolderScrap.userImg,new UserImageListener(viewHolderScrap.userImg));   
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName() + "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getReview().getReview()).toString();
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(activityText);

            ss.setSpan(new MyClickableSpan(activityText, mFeedViewData.getReview().getId()), 0, mFeedViewData.getReview().getReviewerName().length(), Spanned.SPAN_COMPOSING);
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setText(ss);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderScrap.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }               
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
        else if(mFeedViewData.getActivity().length()>0){
            String activityText = Html.fromHtml("<b>" + "A user: "+ "</b>" + " "+ mFeedViewData.getActivity()).toString();
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setText(activityText);
            if(minutes!=0){
                viewHolderScrap.timeline.setText( minutes + " minutes ago");                    
            }   
            viewHolderScrap.userImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_blank_profile);
        }

        if(feedType == Utils.ADAPTER_FEED_TUTORIAL){
            viewHolderScrap.userActivity.setClickable(false);
            viewHolderScrap.objImg.setClickable(false);
        }

    }

    return arg1;
}
```

Comment: post getView() method of adapter

Comment: optimised solution is Use one main layout & multiple row child layout attach in mainlayout as per needed show hide that row layout in getview(....) method & for load image use solution of @Alessandro Mattioli suggested.

Comment: have attached the getView() method

Comment: Wow! Do you really need this all logic in getView() method? Performance gets lost in this method for sure.

Comment: I can do away with some of the logic . But most of the logic used a are pretty straight forward i believe(Non time consuming).

Comment: @Chirag_RB You produce a lot of objects by concatenating strings. Those strings will cause GC to run, which will make ListView slower. Also Html.fromHtml() are really slow calls. They use HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not load or process any images in `Adapter.getView()` method. If you need to do so, do it in a separate [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). If you download images from Internet you should better use some helper libraries like [Volley](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)

Comment: I am using Universal Image Loader . I don't think it is because of the Images but because of multiple row layouts. When I tried with a single row layout it scrolls smoothly .

Comment: Ok. What else you can check is: (a) you should reuse views, (b) row layout must be as flat at possible. If possible, use LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I use this library to load images in list view, I never had a problem:[Android Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: I am also using it . I don't think it is because of the Images but because of multiple rows . When I tried with a single row type it scrolls smoothly .